# Improving accuracy of a voice detection algorithm

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, machine-learning, c#-3.0, voice-recognition

So I have this Mono audio file that contains people talking, talking pauses and then them talking again. While they are talking and while they're not talking, there are children crying in the background from time to time, cars' breaks' squealing, things you hear when you are outside.

My goal is to keep those parts when they are talking and to cut those parts when they are not talking out. It is not necessary to filter the background noises.

Basically my final goal is to have a cut list like this

```
Start in seconds, End in seconds
```

What have I tried?

1. I manually created a voice only file by fitting together all of those parts that contain speech.(10 seconds)
2. I manually created a noise only file by fitting together all of those parts that do not contain speech.(50 seconds)
3. I got the frequencies + amplitudes thereof by applying a Fast Fourier transform
4. I walk through the audio file each 100 ms and take a FFT snapshot
5. I put all values of one snapshot(in my case 512) in a List and feed it to a machine learning algorithm(numl) combined with a label (in the first case voice = true and in the second case voice = false)
6. Then I use my main audio file, do basically the same but this time use the result of my machine learning model to determine whether it is speech or not and output the time in seconds it realizes this.

My problem is that I get a lot of false positives and false negatives. It seems to recognize voice when there is none and vice versa.

Is the reason for this probably a badly trained model(I use a decision tree) or do I need to take other measures to get a better result?

Comment: use a PCA to separate the primary speaker and the background noise should give you better data to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The common misconception about speech is that it is treated as an unrelated sequence of data frames. The core property of speech is that it is a continuous process in time, not just an array of data points.

Any reasonable VAD should take account of that and use time-oriented classifiers like HMMs. In your case any classifier that takes time into account would it be a simple energy-based voice activity detection that monitors background level or a GMM-HMM based VAD will do way better than any static classifier.

For description of simple algorithms  you can check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection).

If you are looking for a good sophisticated VAD implementation, you can find one in WebRTC project, this VAD was developed by Google:

https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/webrtc/common_audio/vad/

Comment: Do you have a c# implementation of that?

Comment: You can use C code from C# by plugging it through interop. There is very little chance you can find a good VAD in C# just because most of them are implemented in C/C++/Matlab.

Comment: Please share how to use this very VAD by google in c# in an example by editing your reply for everyone to see.

Comment: @Gewinn why don't you try it for yourself and let us know about your findings ?

Comment: Please share how to use this very VAD by google in c# in an example by editing your reply for everyone to see.